# Why wont this CSS float images into columns in chrome

Tags: html, css

When I try to float my images they stay stuck in one big column instead of splitting into two columns. The float code is towards bottom of css here.  Why would this be happening?

I would post html too but whenever I do it automatically converts into displaying content:(?

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

a h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-header{
  padding-top: 17px;
  height: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, transparent 40%),
            linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, transparent 50%),
            url('../MarxBros.jpg') no-repeat center;
 }

.intro{
  text-align: center;
 }
 .secondary-content{
   width: 45%;
   padding-left:50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   margin:auto;
   max-width:960px;
 }

.quote1,.quote3,.quote5{
  float:left;
 }
.quote2,.quote4,.quote6{
  float:right;
 }
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
 }
```

Comment: Add your HTML and select it and click on `{}`  icon to format it.

Comment: Bookmark the formatting guide, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

If the image container is greater than the width of two images (plus margins/padding), but less than three, you should only need to float all images left and they will line up in two columns:

Like this:

CSS:

```
.container {
width:600px;
height:600px;
border:1px solid #282828;
padding:-10px;
}
.box {
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:20px;
background: #ebebeb;
float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
<div class = "box"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sj4ek7cx/)

Comment: so my width or max-width is too large?

Comment: I don't know how big your images are.  If you have all images floated left and get one column, then your container width is less than the width of 2 images (plus margins/padding)